# GAE Python - Ereporter doesn't send email

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I want to use the ereporter to send me a daily email with all exceptions from my app. To do so I am using the following code:

```
import webapp2, logging
from google.appengine.ext import ereporter

class SomeJob(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
     try:
        #some job
     except:
        logging.exception('my text')
        ereporter.register_logger()
```

My app.yaml has following reference (Python2.7):

```
- url: /_ereporter.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.ereporter.report_generator.application
  login: admin
```

And my cron.yaml has following:

```
- description: Daily exception report
  url: /_ereporter?sender=email@mydomain.com&delete=false&to=myown@email.com
  schedule: every day 04:30
```

The cron job works without errors, it just doesn't send an email. What I have noticed, is that when I look in the App Dashboard and go to Log, the exception logged has following text:

> my text
>   None

I am not sure what is causing the "None" to be added, but I am suspecting that it could indicate why I am not receiving the daily report. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe add `except Exception as e:` and then repr the error to be more specific?

Comment: Well yes, I have some jobs where I register the entire Traceback result. However I used a simple string here to show that even that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess the the problem is you register the logger after you log your data.

In the [ereporter article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/python/recording_exceptions_with_ereporter) it recommends registering the logger at global level:

```
import logging
from google.appengine.ext import ereporter

ereporter.register_logger()
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Samuel. That did solve the "None" issue. However the email is still not being sent.

Comment: Turns out that just logging an exception doesn't trigger ereporter. When an actual exception happened recently, I did receive an email.

Answer (score 1):

As Samuel noted, you must register the logger before the exception is thrown. The best place is in your equivalent of main.py. Once you do that, though, you should see the results of your calls to logging.exception(). ereporter will send you all unhandled exceptions *and* all exceptions where you call logging.exception() in the except: clause.

One caveat with ereporter is that it defaults to sending only yesterday's exceptions. To get it to send you today's exceptions call it manually and provide today's date, e.g.,

```
http://your-app.appspot.com/_ereporter?sender=admin@yourdomain.com&date=2014-05-28
```

You could also write your own cron handler to wrap the _ereporter and provide today's date programmatically, something like this:

```
self.redirect("/_ereporter ... &date=%s" % datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

I plan to do that so that I can get an hourly exception report.

H/T: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-appengine/ereporter/google-appengine/G99VGhs5cls/bD1UXDEnQqcJ